# How to distinguish instance variables from class variables when typing python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mypy

I'm a bit confused about the way python deals with instance variables vs. class variables when trying to set up robust typing (in python >3.5). In this example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
...

class Film(base):
    __tablename__ = 'films'

    # Class variables
    title = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    director = Column(String)
    year = Column(String)

    # Instance variables
    def __init__(self: 'Film', title: str, director: str, year: int) -> None:
        self.director = director
        self.title = title
        self.year = year


f = Film(title="WWE Greatest Blunders", director="Vince McMahon", year=2020)

# Types according to printout:
print(str(type(Film.title)) + " " + str(Film.title))
# <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute'> Film.title
print(str(type(f.title)) + " " + str(f.title))
# <class 'str'> WWE Greatest Blunders

# Types according to mypy:
y = Film.title      
# y: Column
x = f.title         
# x: Column
```

In this example, the class has to have class variables of type Column in order for sqlalchemy to work. But when I create instances of this class, we have to use strings, integers, etc. for the various properties. I'd like mypy to recognize these primitive python types when dealing with class instances.

My guesses are that:

- This won't be possible, but then this feels like a (minor) failing on either mypy typings, sqlalchemy, or python itself.
- Sqlalchemy is being inexact by requiring you to declare class variables as Column types, but then expecting you to set instances with primitive types.
- More generally, it is poor practice to declare class variables as one type, and then use instance variables of the same name with a different type.

Any solutions/suggestions about this situation?

Comment: Searching for "mypy sqlalchemy" brings up [this project](https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs), which says it solves at least some of those sorts of problems, in at least some situations, by using type stubs and a mypy plugin. Sounds like that's how it's done.

Comment: Thanks! Just the sort of info/initiative I was looking for. Also gives some reassurance I wasn't bonkers in thinking something was up here.